# adding two number using pointers

Tags: c, pointers

I found this code in the internet for adding two numbers using pointers.
couldn't understand how it is working? Any help would be appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
int main()
{
      int  a,b,sum;
      char *p;
      printf("Enter 2 values : ");
      scanf("%d%d",&a,&b);
      p = (char *)a; // Using pointers
      sum = (int)&p[b];
      printf("sum = %d",sum);
      getch(); 
      return 0;
}
```

Comment: It isn't working; it invokes undefined behaviour

Comment: Its working fine in my computer I m using Dev IDE. might be because of scanf("%lu%lu,&a,&b) change it to scanf("%d,%d",&a,&b)

Comment: its a pointer related question thats why added c++ tag

Comment: It's perfectly good C code. It doesn't contain anything C++ specific. Never, ever, never abuse pointers like this.

Comment: ok got it remember next time while posting question

Answer (score 5):

The following line interprets the value in `a` as an address:

```
p = (char *)a;
```

`&p[b]` is the address of the `b` th element of the array starting at `p`.  So, as each element of the array has a size of 1, it's a char pointer pointing at address `p+b`.  As `p`  contains `a`,  it's the address at `p+a`.

Finally, the following line converts back the pointer to an int:

```
 sum = (int)&p[b];
```

But needless to say:  it's a weird construct.

## Additional remarks:

Please note that there are limitations, according to the C++ standard:

> **5.2.10/5:** A value of integral type (...) can be explicitly converted to a pointer.
>
> **5.2.10/4**:  A pointer can be explicitly converted to any integral type large enough to hold it.

So better verify that `sizeof(int) >= sizeof(char*)`.

Finally, although this addition will work on most implementations, this is not a guaranteed behaviour on all CPU architectures, because the mapping function between integers and pointers is implementation-defined:

> A pointer converted to an integer of sufficient size (if any such
> exists on the implementation) and back to the same pointer type will
> have its original value; mappings between pointers and integers are
> otherwise implementation-defined.

Comment: table?? it should be array right ? and what about the size??

Answer (score 2):

First `a` is converted to a pointer with the same value. It doesn't point to anything really, it's just the same value.

The expression `p[b]` will add `b` to `p` and refer to the value at that position.

Then the address of the `p[b]` element is taken and convert to an integer.

Comment: so is does the size factor doesnt come into play when finding the sum i.e. sum = (int)&p[b]

Comment: The size of what? The size of `int` and `char*`: If the pointers are 64-bit, the `int` type is still probably 32-bit, so that will be the limiting factor. The size of `p[b]`: Since `p` is `char*`, `p[b]` refers to `p+b*sizeof(char)`. If `p` was `int*`, the `p[b]` would refer to `p+b*sizeof(int)`.

Answer (score 2):

As commented, it is valid, but horrible code - just a party trick.

```
p = (char *)a;
```

`p` takes the value of `a` entered as a supposed address.

```
sum = (int)&p[b];
```

the address of the `b`th element of a `char` array is at `p + b`.

Since `p == a` (numerically), the correct sum is obtained.

To take a worked example, enter 46 and 11.

```
p = (char *)a;            // p = 46
sum = (int)&p[b];         // the address of p[b] = 46 + 11 = 57
```

Note: nowhere is `*p` or `p[b]` written or read, and size does not matter - except for the `char` array, where pointer arithmetic is in units of `1`.

Comment: Thanks, after seeing this I understood I just magically interpolated the line `p = (char*)a;` as `p = (char*)&a;`

Comment: @JonathanMee that's how I saw it at first, and considered swapping the order of `a` and `b` declarations to break it.